# How do I insert a commit using git?

Tags: git

I need to insert a commit in the master branch of my git repository whist preserving the subsequent merges and commits.

I currently have something like this

```
A--B--C--D--E--F     master
       \     \  
        G--H  I--J   branches
```

and need to insert a commit K such that the new structure becomes

```
A--B--K              master
    \
     C--D--E--F      new branch
      \     \  
       G--H  I--J    old branches
```

I'm not even sure if this is possible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
git checkout master
git branch new_branch # copy current branch master to new_branch
git reset --hard B    # now master points to B
(hack, hack, hack)
git commit -m K       # K on B in master
```

Answer (score 2):

Rename the "master" branch to "new branch". Then checkout the commit B, start a new branch called "master" from there, and make your changes. Something like follows should do it (not tested).

```
git branch -m master new_branch
git branch master B
git checkout master
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This results in commit A being a member of "new branch" and not "master". The history for master then becomes "B--K" rather than the intended "A--B--K". This same structure could be achieved (with differing branch names) by simply branching from B and committing K.

Comment: @Jason I know I'm 4 years late to the party here, and your account seems to be gone; but commit A would be a member of both "new_branch" and "master".  It is a tree, and many branches can share the same ancestors.  Of course, it might be notated one way or the other (e.g. by `git log --graph --oneline --all`), but that's just a notation - `git log master` and `git log new_branch` will show both have A.  It's also true of your suggestion for creating this same structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
# git checkout -b new-master B
```

Now make your changes for K, commit them and voilá, there’s the structure you want. :)